# SAPUI5 Android App - resources not loading

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I have a problem with my SAPUI5 Application. I export my App with Eclipse and phonegap and if i use the following resources for the sap-ui-core.js the exported app is not starting on my tablet. The screen stops by loading with a light blue screen. I've downloaded the runtime from here [sapui5](http://openui5.org/download.html)

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.ux3, sap.ui.table, sap.ui.core, sap.viz, sap.suite.ui.commons, sap.uxap, sap.ui.layout"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>
```

Now if i change my src-path to the sap-ui-core.js file on the server of sapui5 everthing works fine and the app is running. The Path above is correct because my other files like the css file are loading correctly (same root)

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.ux3, sap.ui.table, sap.ui.core, sap.viz, sap.suite.ui.commons, sap.uxap, sap.ui.layout"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when running my UI5 App on a mobile device using cordova. However, in my case it helped to wait for `deviceready` in my index.html like `document.addEventListener("deviceready", fnDeviceReady)` and `sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(fnInit)`. Apparently, there were some timing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon that you are using UI5 Runtime Mobile library. As the [this link](http://openui5.org/download.html) states to use Runtime Mobile for Mobile development. The libraries you included during bootstraping as below.

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.ux3, sap.ui.table, sap.ui.core, sap.viz, sap.suite.ui.commons, sap.uxap, sap.ui.layout"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>
```

**UI5 Runtime Mobile :** doesn't support all the above libraries. The file contains control libraries such as: `sap.m, sap.ui.core,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.suite,sap.ui.unified.` Refer [this](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/293eb945f0e945aaa776812481b4c533.html) documentation regarding the Hybrid Mobile App Development for better understanding.